# Why does trying to print enum class in c++ give an error?

Tags: c++

I want to print u that has km as unit

```
enum class Unit { km, m, cm };

int main()
{
Unit u = Unit::km; 
std::cout<<u; 
return 0; 
}
```

Why do i get an error?

error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘Unit’)
```

Comment: **Always** include the verbatim error message(s) when you have questions about errors you receive when compiling code. It should be [included in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65342305/edit)

Comment: When I run it I get `error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope` so I assume it's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Unit` enum is a scoped enumeration, `enum class`, these types of enums don't allow implicit casting. You'll have to expliticly cast if you want it to work with `cout`:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(u);
```

Comment: better use `std::underlying_type` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Fair enough, in this example its guaranteed to be `int` though.